# d3.geo coastal towns not projected on world map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, d3.js, geocoding, world-map

I am using d3.js (specifically d3.geo) to project trade routes between different locations based on data from a mongodb datastore. The geocodes for the locations are queried from google maps api, and the geojson used for are extracted from a .shp file from http://naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vector.

I referenced [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/ilyabo/2209220) to create the visualisation. Most of trade routes appear, however if one of the route's location is a coastal city/town, e.g. San Francisco, the route will not be projected on the chart. My suspicion is that the geocode (lat, lon) of the location cannot append itself to a path as it is not out of the coastal bounds of any of the paths. Any pointers to this slight problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code please? We can't really guess what's wrong without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: I have figured out what was wrong in the code. Location names with spaces (e.g. "San Francisco") could not generate paths with visible colors. I used the following function to generate the path colors:

Comment: `var gradientNameFun = function(d) {
    return "grd" + d.origin.Name.substring(0,3) + d.dest.Name.substring(0,3);
};`